# Nothing works on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04

On my computer I had installed wine like i had many times before, but then i went to turn on my vpn before i went to game and it wouldn't turn on. So I opened my terminal to reboot the network stuff and things were reset. I rebooted thinking it just needed reboot, but now the keyboard wont work, the mouse wont work, and gnome desktop had been deleted and things are all just messed up. Is there any way to fix this somehow?

Comment: have you tried fixing any broken dependancies with "sudo apt install -f" and if your using Private Internet Access for your VPN you can't have it installed in your home directory if its encrypted, using root move it to your /opt directory and use a sim link to it

Comment: Your problem may not be the same bu here's a link describing rescuing process upon accidentally uninstalling/removing desktop https://askubuntu.com/questions/1033789/how-to-recover-graphical-ui-after-accidently-uninstalling/

Comment: Can you post some screenshots or some more info. It's pretty common to lose the GUI like this https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears but that's not same as yours if your keyboard and mouse aren't working.

Comment: The thing with this is, I already reinstalled Ubuntu, but the login prompt was there, but the box was formatted and didn't look like it should and I couldn't open a terminal or move my mouse or anything. I also know I didn't uninstall my desktop, as it was there and functioning, just all input was gone. Also, before rebooted, i opened termianl to do something and it didnt work and the color scheme was all formatted and didnt work. Im not worrying about it anymore, as i just reinstall ubuntu