# I uninstalled pulseaudio; desktop gone

Tags: kubuntu, kde, 19.10

Today my Bluetooth headset on my laptop did not work, so I followed an instruction where I was told to delete and reinstall pulseaudio. I did that, I rebooted my laptop and suddenly got the message "A shell script got lost.Please contact distribution."

My KDE desktop is gone. How do I get the desktop back?

Comment: Does this help? -https://askubuntu.com/questions/1033789/how-to-recover-graphical-ui-after-accidently-uninstalling

Comment: Will i loose my files with this?

Comment: Did it work for you?

Comment: @greatgesture It should not lead to any data loss - but as always, do maintain a good backup of stuff you don't want to loose.

Comment: no packagaes where found, what should I do now? :(

Comment: Sorry to hear that. Try adazem009's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to access command line via recovery mode.
If you haven't changed your root password before, you can access it easily. If you have, you'll need to remember the password.

**If you're on legacy (MBR):**

Press SHIFT until you see the grub menu.

**If you're on UEFI:**

Press Esc until you see the grub menu.

---

Go to "Advanced options for Ubuntu" and select "Ubuntu with Linux-.... (recovery mode)". Wait until it boots up and select "root". It should ask you to give the root password. If you haven't changed it before, you can press CTRL+D to continue. Type the root password and try these commands to reinstall KDE Plasma and boot Kubuntu:

```
apt update
apt install -y kubuntu-desktop
systemctl reboot
```

You can also try to disable boot animation to see what's wrong.

```
vi /etc/default/grub
```

OR

```
nano /etc/default/grub
```

(use your preferred text editor)

Find this line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

and change it to this:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="text"
```

Save the file and run this command:

```
update-grub
```

Reboot...

If you don't have root access in recovery mode or recovery mode doesn't boot up (ending up with the same error), then you'll need to boot from the live CD, chroot your Kubuntu installation and try those commands there.
I̲f̲ ̲y̲o̲u̲ ̲c̲a̲n̲'̲t̲ ̲r̲e̲c̲o̲v̲e̲r̲ ̲y̲o̲u̲r̲ ̲K̲u̲b̲u̲n̲t̲u̲ ̲i̲n̲s̲t̲a̲l̲l̲a̲t̲i̲o̲n̲,̲ ̲t̲h̲e̲n̲ ̲y̲o̲u̲ ̲c̲a̲n̲ ̲b̲a̲c̲k̲u̲p̲ ̲y̲o̲u̲r̲ ̲f̲i̲l̲e̲s̲ ̲f̲r̲o̲m̲ ̲t̲h̲e̲ ̲l̲i̲v̲e̲ ̲C̲D̲ ̲a̲n̲d̲ ̲r̲e̲i̲n̲s̲t̲a̲l̲l̲ ̲K̲u̲b̲u̲n̲t̲u̲.̲

If your bluetooth headset doesn't work again, check what's the cause of your issue. Don't reinstall audio drivers if you just can't connect to the headset.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: I would like to underline this important sentence by adazem009: "If you can't recover your Kubuntu installation, then you can backup your files from the live CD and reinstall Kubuntu." Even if you are not able to solve (but I wish you'll solve it), at least you can (and must!) copy your important data in an external drive